# How to create custom number picker in android?

Tags: android, numberpicker

How can I implement custom number picker in android the same below image?

[image: numberpicker]

I have checked android arsenal library did not work any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7169, https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3817, and https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4502 all seem to implement the general pattern that you are seeking. Use them directly, or look at their implementation to see how they do it. My guess is that they use a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have checked that link that is not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your dependencies in **build.gradle**:

**implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.12'**

Add the exact code to your .xml file:

```
<com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:dividerPadding="10dp"
    app:np_dividerColor="#03A9F4"
    app:np_dividerDistance="30dp"
    app:np_dividerThickness="5dp"
    app:np_dividerType="underline"
    app:np_height="180dp"
    app:np_itemSpacing="-10dp"
    app:np_max="59"
    app:np_min="0"
    app:np_selectedTextColor="#2196F3"
    app:np_textColor="#CB6A6A6A"
    app:np_textSize="20dp"
    app:np_selectedTextSize="20dp"
    app:np_value="3"
    app:np_width="64dp" />
```

For more customization you can check this [GitHub link](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker).

Design will look something like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have custom values inside your number picker you can do something like this:

**First create an array with your values(this will go to the number picker)**

```
String mValues[] = { "100 ", "200 ","300"};
```

**Now use this method to create number picker with custom values:**

```
 private void setNubmerPicker(NumberPicker nubmerPicker,String [] numbers ){
    nubmerPicker.setMaxValue(numbers.length-1);
    nubmerPicker.setMinValue(0);
    nubmerPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    nubmerPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);
}
```

**And for the final step call this method:**

```
  setNubmerPicker(yourNumberPicker,mValues);
```

You can put any string that you want inside the array- "44", "127" and "Female".

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question of how to create a custom number picker.

Comment: what about xml  layout bro

Comment: @CommonsWare what is your suggestion then

Comment: Could you tell me what I did wrong? Because I was sure that by "custom" he only meant custom values.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul: I suspect that the "custom" is the look, not the value list.

Comment: @CommonsWare , could be. if it is the case I will edit my question. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: thats not I want I have checked them already please first check my questions

Comment: @EdgarShvedskiy I did check your question but something is not clear, do you want the same look? the same color? the same divider of the number picker? Could you be a bit more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to implement the same look

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I want to implement the same look

Comment: @TamirAbutbul what do you think main problem